# SharePoint Online - Display Image on a Page based on column status value from list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps

I'm trying to showcase a traffic light image on a SharePoint sites homepage based on a status value. Basically, we have a list of "IT Systems" on a list, and it has "Status" column "Red", "Amber", "Green". So if any system is down, we want to change its status which should reflect on the home page depending on the status selected "Red", "Amber", "Green". I'm not sure how to achieve this on SharePoint online.

Comment: You can format your list using JSON formatting and then add list on site page using [List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224). Let me know if this approach works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no out-of-the-box way to achieve this in SharePoint Online. You can look for help from 3rd party tools.